# Query SELECT * AS not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to do something simple I want to run two queries inside one with a combined result.

I've written the following code:

```
database.query('SELECT * FROM `inventories` WHERE `status` = ' + 1 + ' AS `liveInventory`, SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `balance` >= ' + 0.00 + ' AS `liveBalances`', function(error, call) {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }

    console.log(call);
});
```

Resulting in the following error;

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `liveInventory`, SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `balance` >= 0 AS `liveBalances`' at line 1
>       `

Isn't the syntax correct?

Comment: I'm unable to understand why you are using two select statement in one query?

Comment: Putting these two queries together like this also makes no sense on MySQL.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Not strictly related, but why are you concatenating a constant to a constant, the `+ 1 +`? Why not just write `"where status = 1"`?

Comment: If you want to combine results of queries you have to either use joins or set operators. Try to describe what you want to do here to get more detailed pointers.

Comment: @all

I've always thought this was possible, never tried it.  I'd like to run both these queries and both have their output that I can use from to go; for example to access the results from the inventories call I'd just do `call.liveInventory.forEach({...})`

Comment: You're getting a lot of push back here, but it's actually pretty normal to do what you're doing. You just need to use sub-queries to produce the computed fields within a larger `SELECT`.

Comment: Err, sorry, I misread your queries. It's pretty normal to do this when you're trying to select *single* computed fields, something like `select (select count(*) from A) as a_count, (select count(*) from B) as b_count`. But you're trying to select two *sets*   of data, which is not at all a normal thing to do. You need to use two separate queries for this.

Comment: @meagar okay, that will do then, I just hate to have queries inside queries inside queries, it gets real messy.

Comment: @VGOExclusive You cannot do this with "queries inside queries". You need two different queries, executed sequentially.

Comment: @VGOExclusive It seems like you're over complicating this. It would possible to answer this questions with a "nested" solution, but it's probably not the way you want to go. I'd separate them entirely into two different calls. If you happen to be using promises, this would be straightforward to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases for columns or tables, but not the result of a where clause.

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.
>
> [Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html)

There are [some better explained examples on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) demonstrating how MySQL aliases generally work.